Estimates of the derivatives of $\Xi(s)$
The $\Xi$ Function is defined by $\Xi(s)=\xi(\frac{1}{2}+is)$, where $\xi(s)=\frac{1}{2}s(s-1)\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)$.
This is a problem from my homework: since we can write it as a power series $\Xi(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{2n}s^{2n}$, prove that for $n=1,2,\cdots,$
$$|A_{2n}|\le\dfrac{(\ln2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$
I think Cauchy's inequality would help but I have no idea about how to estimate $|\Xi(s)|$. Also, I have tried other methods, such as estimating directly according to some formulas of $A_{2n}$, like
$$|A_{2n}|=4\int_0^\infty \dfrac{d}{dx}[\psi'(x)x^\frac{3}{2}]x^{-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{(\ln\sqrt{x})^{2n}}{(2n)!}dx, $$
where $\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}$. But still no progress. So I hope anyone could help. Thanks.
